# Sodalime method for multiple functional groups

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

what exactly happens? I get a little confused when it comes to multi functional groups. can some one explain soda lime as simple as they can.
I apologize if its a really simple question but I'm a high school student.
some good weblinks would be very helpful.

Comment: __Hint__ : ketones don't undergo hydrolysis, but esters go. What is the product?

Comment: so, from the hint ive concluded that ester will undergo nucleophilic substitution to give carboxylic acid which in turn will undergo soda lime, and become  alkane. is that it (●'◡'●)

Comment: Soda lime is usually used to induce decarboxylation https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/acids/decarbox.html

Comment: Almost, as I couldn't call it alkane cuz it has keto group :)